# DOM not updating in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, twitter-digits

I am using AngularJs with angular ui router.
On my homepage I have 'ng-app' declared in HTML tag.

The homepage is something like this

```
<html  ng-app="grwebapp.sidebarlogin">
<head>
.
.
.
<script id="digits-sdk" src="https://cdn.digits.com/1/sdk.js" async></script>

    <script>
    var userphone
//I assume digits-sdk is something loaded in the above script file. 
    document.getElementById('digits-sdk').onload = function() {

  Digits.init({ consumerKey: 'some-key' });
  Digits.embed({
//the container just tells where to place the digits box. 
//In this case I have provided it an 'id' of a div element.
  container: '#my-digits-container',
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
....
 <div ui-view ng-controller="sidebarloginCtrl"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The grwebapp.sidebarlogin.js has a relevant state something like this:

```
.state('/', {
        url:'/',
        templateUrl: '/angularapp/sidebarlogin.html',

        controller: 'sidebarloginCtrl',
});
```

And finally there is sidebarlogin.html which is placed in the **ui-view** div

```
some code....
<div id="my-digits-container" ></div>
some code.....
```

**The above div is wrapped in a modal.**

My problem is the 'digits box' is loaded in google chrome. But in mozilla firefox it loads sometimes and sometimes it doesnt. Also I have found that if I move the 'ng-app' to 'body' tag then the 'digits box' loads in firefox but now I am in doubt if it will always load in firefox. I assume I am missing the app flow here or something.

Also in case of google chrome the modal height changes according to the size of the 'digits box' but in case of mozilla firefox and internet explorer the 'digits box' appears with a vertical scrollbar.

**Update 25 jun 2016:**

I have tried to use directive 
In the new update, I have kept the digit-sdk on the homepage

Homepage

```
<script id="digits-sdk" src="https://cdn.digits.com/1/sdk.js" async>
```

My script of digits is now in a directive:

```
app.directive("digitDir", function() {
    var userphone

    document.getElementById('digits-sdk').onload = function() {

  Digits.init({ consumerKey: 'some-key' });
Digits.embed({
  container: '#my-digits-container',
  theme: {
   /* Input fields borders */
  },
  phoneNumber: '+91',

})
};
return {

    };
});
```

and the template sidebarlogin.html now has the directive tag like this

```
<div id="my-digits-container" ></div>
<div digit-dir></div>
```

I have also tried place the 'digit-dir' div above and within the "my-digit-container" div. But in firefox it still doesnt work.

From what I have debug this time the following code is not firing.

```
document.getElementById('digits-sdk').onload = function(){.....
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Two small things: 1) If you are passing a controller to a state, you don't need to declare the ng-controller property on your ui-view tag. 2) You are missing and ending script tag after the 'digits' section.

Comment: In the original code I have the ending script tag. Since I rewrote this in shorter version here, i forgot it.

Comment: this won't work the way you expect, because the `digits-sdk` and `angular` don't know about each other.  There isn't any enforced configuration requiring one to load before the other, and the digits-sdk is hardwired to look for `my-digits-container` which may or may not have been rendered when it loads.  In order for this to function, you will have to wrap the digits-sdk inside an angular directive to ensure that angular can tell it when to load.

Answer (score 0):

you should ng-app in body itself

```
<div ui-view ng-controller="sidebarloginCtrl"></div>
```

and remove ng-controller from the above div because you are already declaring that in your states

You directive is not the correct way according to angular

```
app.directive("digitDir", function() {


};
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span></span>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

                document.getElementById('digits-sdk').onload = function() {

  Digits.init({ consumerKey: 'some-key' });
Digits.embed({
  container: '#my-digits-container',
  theme: {
   /* Input fields borders */
  },
  phoneNumber: '+91',

})                    
        }
});
```

Return proper structure of the  directive